# Using Control Flow Guard on Mono

Tags: .net, memory, mono, virtual-memory

.NET applications can use [Control Flow Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/control-flow-guard) to protect their memory. But what happens when you run these applications on mono in Linux? I have seen a third party application that got killed because of excessive memory usage on CentOS 7. My server ran out of memory and tries to find processes that to kill through the OOM killer. Processes that use allot of memory are more likely to get killed because they free up most memory. My server logged this:

```
Aug 31 23:41:58 MyServer kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 14401 (mono) score 30 or sacrifice child
Aug 31 23:41:58 MyServer kernel: Killed process 539 (thirdpartyapp) total-vm:3514468kB, anon-rss:26508kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

The app used about 3.5GB of virtual memory and has Control Flow Guard enabled. I believe the usage of CFG has resulted in a higher OOM score so the app got killed. Does anyone know if CFG has a negative impact on the OOM killer, or on Linux as a whole?

Comment: CFG is for non-managed code running on Windows, there are different implementations for Linux that use different names (CFG is a Microsoft name), so how are you "enabling" it on Linux using .Net code? Cross-compiling using LLVM after an AOT of the .Net code? ... ?

Comment: Can't you just enable it and run the code on Mono?

Comment: "I have seen a third party application that got killed because of excessive memory usage on CentOS 7" For third party products, talk to its vendors. If they never support Mono and Linux and only assume you run the app on Windows, anything (bad) can happen.

Comment: @Martin No, CFG is for "non-managed" code on Windows. Even the MS link in your question shows it is only for c/c++ as MSVC inserts CFG instrumentation in the code that interacts with the Windows Kernel at runtime.

Comment: @LexLi The vendor supports mono. This is the official way to run the app on Linux.

Comment: @SushiHangover So you're saying CFG does not function on Mono at all?